# Show that $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ is open in $\mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{R})$ by showing that the complement is closed?

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, solution-verification, normed-spaces

I would like to  that $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ is open in $\mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{R})$, I know there are posts on it but I would like to know what can be said about my proof especially if it is false and what can be made to improve the argument I used if this argument is valid of course..

My attempt :
Consider the complement of $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ in $\mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{R})$ in order to show that it is a closed set.

Consider a sequence of matrices $(A_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\in (\mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{R})\setminus GL_n(\mathbb{R}))^{\mathbb{N}}$ which converges to $A$. First, we notice that

$$
\forall n\in\mathbb{N}, \forall B\in GL_n(\mathbb{R}), \exists\delta>0 : \lVert A_n - B\rVert > \delta
$$

since this sequence does not intersect $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$. And we know that :

$$
\forall\epsilon>0, \exists N\in\mathbb{N} : n\geq N\implies \lVert A_n - A\rVert < \epsilon
$$

The idea is to choose $\epsilon < \delta$. This gives us an $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that

$$
0 \leq\lVert A_n - A\rVert < \epsilon <\delta < \lVert A_n - B\rVert
$$

Then we have $\forall B\in GL_n(\mathbb{R}), \exists N\in\mathbb{N}, \forall n\geq N$:

$$
\lVert A - B\rVert = \lVert (A_n - B) - (A_n - A)\rVert\geq \big\lvert \lVert A_n - B\rVert - \lVert A_n - A\rVert \big\rvert > 0
$$

and we conclude by the fact that since it holds for all $B\in GL_n(\mathbb{R})$, $A$ must not belong to $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ so the complement of $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ in $\mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{R})$ is closed.

Is this proof correct and if not please could you explain why ?

Thak you a lot !

Comment: Note that you didn't use any property of $GL_n(\mathbb R)$, so if this proof were correct, it could be used to show that the complement of any subset is closed.

Comment: @doetoe You are right. But to be honest, as it is, I am unable to see my error in reasoning and I know that there is one.

Comment: @coboy your proof is not tracking quantifiers carefully enough. For instance, $\delta$ depended on little $n$,but this dependence is lost when you choose $\epsilon$

Comment: @hunter You're right. I'm trying to think of a solution but from the moment I index my delta I can't have a "uniform threshold" to exploit to get my inequalities... Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the very first inequality, $\delta$ depends on $B$ and on $n$, but you treat it as being independent of $n$ later on in the proof when you say

> The idea is to choose $\epsilon < \delta$. This gives us an $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that
> $$
> 0 \leq\lVert A_n - A\rVert < \epsilon <\delta < \lVert A_n - B\rVert
> $$

You didn't write it, but implicitly you want this to hold for all $n\ge N$. You can choose $\epsilon$ smaller than any particular $\delta(n,B)$, but you cannot necessarily guarantee that $\epsilon$ will be smaller than $\delta(n,B)$ for infinitely many distinct values of $n$. Similarly, when you say

> Then we have $\forall B\in GL_n(\mathbb{R}), \exists N\in\mathbb{N}, \forall n\geq N$:
> $$
> \lVert A - B\rVert = \lVert (A_n - B) - (A_n - A)\rVert\geq \big\lvert \lVert A_n - B\rVert - \lVert A_n - A\rVert \big\rvert > 0
> $$

Again, presumably the very last inequality cannot be guaranteed to hold because $\delta$ depends on both $n$ and $B$, but you ask for it to hold independently of either of these parameters.

---

Here is a similar "argument" that illustrates the problem clearly. Suppose we want to prove that $G \stackrel{\Delta}{=} \mathbb R\setminus\big(\{0\}\cup\{1/k:k=1,2,\dots\}\big)$ is open by showing the complement is closed. Consider a sequence $\{a_n\}$ in $\mathbb R\setminus G$ that converges to a number $a$, and imagine for the sake of illustration that our sequence $a_n = 1/n$. (It converges to $0$, but we don't need to know that to illustrate what's wrong with the argument you gave, just that it's a possible sequence.)

For every $x\in G$, and every $n$, there is a $\delta(n,x)$ so that $|a_n-x|>\delta$. If $x$ lies in the interval $(\frac1{n+1},\frac1n)$, then $\delta(n,x) < 1/n$. If you keep running your argument, later on when you want to choose $\epsilon$, you want to choose it to be smaller  than $\delta(n,x)$ for all $n\ge N$, for some large $n$. This is impossible to do if $\epsilon > 0$.

Comment: Thak you for your answer, If I understand well, the fact is that if I keep running my argument, I would like to "take" the infinimum over my $\delta_n$ but I will get something closer to $0$ which is a problem when wanting to keep $\epsilon$ strictly smaller than $\delta$....

Comment: @coboy: that's correct. The infimum over $n,B$ of $\delta(n,B)$ may be $0$ (it actually has to be zero because the set $GL_n$ is open!)

Comment: You took the time to analyze a proof with a lot of mistakes (which is not very fun I imagine, especially when I read it again afterwards..) and that's very nice because I was able to better understand what was wrong. Thank you very much Alex!

Answer (score 4):

The complement is the set $C:=\{A:\det A=0\}$, and the function $\det:M_n(\mathbb R)\to\mathbb R$ is continuous. Since $\{0\}$ is closed in  $\mathbb R$, continuity implies that $C$ is closed.

Comment: This is a nice way to see that the set of invertible matrices is open, but I don't think it addresses the OP's question, which asks whether their proof is correct, and if not, asks for an explanation about what's wrong with their argument.

Comment: Sometimes doing an autopsy of a wrong proof is useful, but sometimes it is not — in this case, there are really too many things wrong with the atempt, to the point that it is not salvageable.There are better ways to spend the OP's time!

Comment: Fair enough :-)

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Thank you for your answer your argument is really nice and I should have thought about it instead of limiting myself to an excessive use of the $\delta-\epsilon$ method in a incorrect way  !

Comment: @coboy, the biggest problem with what you wrote is that you never used the fact that you were working with GL(n), really. Don't worry, with time you'll get used to using more "high level" versions of continuity — it is actually good that you went to epsilons and delta, because you need to practice that too :-)